# How to add javascript variable into mysql database using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, insert

I want to add into mysql database the data from a javascript function:

```
for (var j=0; j < data.length; j++) {

        ......
        Cars[car.owner] = owner;

       <?php
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Cars (owner, year)
        VALUES 

    ?>
    }
```

I want to add into the DATABASE (Cars table), the owner and year that I receive from a "for cicle". Every time I do this "for cicle" I want to add the data into the database. Can you tell me how to do it using PHP?

Comment: You have to use AJAX to do that

Answer (score 0):

Create a PHP file where you have all the code to interact with the database.
Then from your JS file make an AJAX call using POST or GET method.

Example:

This can be in your JS code

```
parameters = "url=" + yourJSObject;
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "yourPHPFile.php", true)
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length)
    request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")
    request.onreadystatechange = function()
        {   
            if (this.readyState == 4)
            {
                 if (this.status == 200)
                    {
                     if (this.responseText != null)
                        {
                            ///You can use this responseText from your PHP file
                        }                       
                    else alert("Ajax error: No data received")
                    }
                else alert( "Ajax error: " + this.statusText)
             }
        }
 request.send(parameter)
```

And this is yourPHPFile code:

```
<?php 
 if (isset($_POST['url']))
 {
    $js_object = $_POST['url']
     /*use this object as you want */
 }
?>
```

EDIT: please refer to this example I wrote [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0W3kWgdIrFAN0RwZ1pieFdGVzQ)

Comment: Sorry for not understanding, I'm not a professional neither in php and ajax.... Can you please tell me what code to use and how. What to put inside phpfile... and more. Thanks

Comment: @MarcoTodeschi Please refer the edit. And nor am I a professional. :)